# Why are votes calculated differently on the question vs. user's reputation?

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

According to [my Reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/619493/amir-gonnen?tab=reputation) in my user profile, I got 1 upvote = 5 rep, 4 downvotes = -4 rep for my question.

**So the question's rep is +1** as it should be:

[image: snippet from reputation history]

But when I look at [the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375473/running-dynamically-generated-c-code-on-the-client-web-browser), **rep is -1**:

[image: question score]

Is this a bug or did I miss something here?

Comment: You actually got **2** downvotes. This cost you 4 rep, for a net rep change of 1, and gives the question a net score of -1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're confusing the post's *score* (which is the number of upvotes minus the number of downvotes) with the *reputation* you gained from it – upvotes count 'heavier' (+5) than downvotes (-2).

Comment: You are right....